# pylint does not ignore modules

Tags: python, pylint

I can't figure out the syntax for running pylint. I need it to skip all django `migrations` folders, but when I run it like so

```
pylint catalog --ignored-modules=migrations
```

I still get my migrations checked:

```
************* Module catalog.migrations.0001_initial
C: 19, 0: Line too long (114/100) (line-too-long)
C:  1, 0: Invalid module name "0001_initial" (invalid-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  8, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
************* Module catalog.migrations.0002_botstateviewtemplate
C: 18, 0: Line too long (114/100) (line-too-long)
C:  1, 0: Invalid module name "0002_botstateviewtemplate" (invalid-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  8, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
************* Module catalog.migrations.0003_delete_botstateviewtemplate
C:  1, 0: Invalid module name "0003_delete_botstateviewtemplate" (invalid-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  8, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
```

What is the proper syntax i'm missing?

**UPDATE** after trying `catalog.migrations`: the problem persists

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `pylint catalog --ignored-modules=catalog.migrations`?

Comment: @alecxe I did - see update above

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to do this is: `pylint catalog --ignore=0001_initial.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
 --ignore=<file[,file…]>
    Add files or directories to the blacklist. They should be base names, not paths.
```

So the right way should be:

```
pylint catalog --ignore=migrations
```